# how to restore Sql server backup using batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sql-server-2016

Below is my batch file which is taking backup but showing an exception "unexcepted argument" on execution of restore command. Pl help me solving this issue, TIA.

One more doubt can I take backup of remote server on my local folder, here I am taking backup on remote machine itself.

```
set SqlServer=.
set InstanceName=MSSQLSERVER
set Username=xxx
set Password=xxxx
set Database=abc
set LocalFolder=C:\db_backups

SqlCmd -S %SqlServer% -U %Username% -P %Password% -Q "Backup Database %Database% To Disk='%LocalFolder%\%Database%-%CurrentDate%.bak'"

SqlCmd -S %SqlServer% -U %Username% -P %Password% –Q "RESTORE DATABASE [test] FROM DISK='%LocalFolder%\%Database%-%CurrentDate%.bak'"
```

Comment: Your problem isn't with the `RESTORE`. The `–Q` argument starts with the `U+2013 EN DASH` character instead of a regular dash.

Comment: I didn't get you, what should be the last line then?

Comment: `SqlCmd -S %SqlServer% -U %Username% -P %Password% -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [test] FROM DISK='%LocalFolder%\%Database%-%CurrentDate%.bak'"`. Same as your line, but different in one crucial character.